# Сompare List<Order> with List<Product> using StreamAPI

Tags: java, java-stream

it is necessary to determine whether this order can be fulfilled: is there enough of each product in stock.I can't figure out how to compare lists using stream

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    private int amount;

    public Product(String name, int amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
class Order {
    private String name;
    private int amount;

    public Order(String name, int amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
class TestWarehouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Product apple = new Product("apple", 3);
        Product juice = new Product("juice", 2);
        Product milk = new Product("milk", 4);

        Order order1 = new Order("apple", 3);
        Order order2 = new Order("juice", 3);
        Order order3 = new Order("milk", 5);

        List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(order1, order2, order3));
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(apple, juice, milk));
//        orderList.stream()
//                .filter()
//                .anyMatch()
    }
}
```

Comment: I m assuming the orderList can have any amount of orders, and can also have orders that are not corresponding to indexes? ie order1 is idx 0 and apple in productList is also idx0

Comment: The List<Order> contains all the products. Indexes may not match List<Product>

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `Map` that contains the amount of each product with `Collectors.groupingBy`. Then, iterate over all the orders and compare the amounts.

```java
Map<String, Integer> freq = productList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Product::getAmount)));
orderList.stream().forEach(order -> {
    boolean works = freq.getOrDefault(order.getName(), 0) >= order.getAmount();
    System.out.println(works); // or do anything else
});
```

Alternatively, if each `Product` in the `productList` has a unique name, then it is simpler to use `Collectors.toMap`.

```java
Map<String, Integer> freq = productList.stream().collect(
          Collectors.toMap(Product::getName, Product::getAmount));
```

Comment: thanks. I will study your answer, but I haven't gone through this yet, right now I can only use filter/anyMatch/all match/flatMap.Collectors is the next topic =)